# How to return a value using python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, testing, multiprocessing

I have a regression test script written in python that calls a number of test scripts also written in python and executes them. Every test script returns either `pass` or `fail`. I want to make sure that the regression test script doesn't wait forever for a return value and stop the running test script after sometime. I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14924210) and it works perfectly well. Except for a small caveat. The `p.join()`  will not return a value from the test script which is essential. I can not use message passing, or a global variable since it is a huge code base used across multiple teams. Can someone please suggest something? I have looked at the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) documentation but I can not seem to find a clear cut answer.

The code runs on Windows machine and python version is 2.7x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Pool` instead, which *will* return the result of the worker function directly:

```
import multiprocessing

def f():
  return "hi"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1) # Just a one-process Pool.
    result = pool.apply_async(f)
    try:
        print(result.get(10)) # Wait 10 seconds
    except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
        print("Timed out")
        pool.terminate() # Kill all (1, in this case) processes in the pool
        pool.join()
```

Comment: but how do I put a timeout in `Pool`? I have to ensure that if the function does not return in sometime, it should stop the script.

Comment: @user1343318 I've edited my answer to show you how to do that.